# Grails 2.0 set logging for own classes

Tags: java, grails, groovy, log4j

How do I set the log4j configuration to log level `DEBUG` only for my own classes - domain, controllers etc? I dont want the information from grails classes (regarding fetching resources etc.), I just want my own debug traces..

I've tried a whole lot of combination, none seems to work i.e.

`debug   'grails.app.controller.test.MainController'` - doesnt work

Comment: have you tried widening it to :    debug   'grails.app'     ?

Comment: yes, this is exactly what I am trying to avoid - I get tons of Grails' debug prints then...

Comment: those should be your debug statements :)

Comment: those are grails' prints, i.e. `2012-02-16 17:03:48,289 INFO pool-3-thread-1 [org.grails.plugin.resource.ResourceProcessor] - <Performing a changed file reload>`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this config snippet in your log4j closure (in Config.groovy):

```
all additivity: false, console: [
  'grails.app.controllers.your.package',
  'grails.app.domain.your.package',
  'grails.app.services.your.package',
  'grails.app.taglib.your.package',
  'grails.app.conf.your.package',
  'grails.app.filters.your.package'
]
```

Comment: I dont know why nor how, but I does exactly what I want :-) Do I have to add all the classes I want to be traced there?

Comment: @Queequeg Classes or packages.

Comment: I also like to separate the logging output from my grails classes to a separate file (not shown above).
I've put the contents of my latest environments-block here: [link](http://snipplr.com/view/63391/grails-log4j-for-different-environments--an-example/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add you log4j info into Config.groovy.  Below is a snippet from one of our projects

```
appenders {
    //console name:'stdout', layout:pattern(conversionPattern: '%c{2} %m%n')
    console name:'stdout', layout:pattern(conversionPattern: '%d %p %t [%c] - <%m>%n')
    rollingFile  name:'file', file:'igive.log', maxFileSize:'2000KB', maxBackupIndex:'5',append:'true',layout:pattern(conversionPattern: '%d{[EEE, dd-MMM-yyyy @ HH:mm:ss.SSS]} [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n')

}

root   {
    info  'file', 'stdout'
    //debug  'file', 'stdout'
    additivity = true
}
//error file: "StackTrace"
//StackTrace="error,file"

warn   'org.codehaus.groovy.grails',
        'org.springframework',
        'org.hibernate',
        'org.apache',
        'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate'

debug  'com.yourpackage'
```

The last line is the important line.  This allows com.yourpackage (replace with your package) to be logged at a debug level.

Comment: I have a controller: `package test ... class TestController ...` and in the config: `debug 'test'` .. and I dont get any output :-(

Comment: I wonder if the 'test' is a keyword and is messing it up ... try renaming your package and class name as well. Get rid of Test, probably not a good name anyways.

Comment: actually, my package is called `invoices` ;-) .. Doesnt work anyway :-(